# Jmeter handling image uploads

Tags: jmeter

I am doing a load testing of website,I have used jmeter recorder to record my script but there is a functionality in which image is being uploaded and that is a third party tool which is being used for uploading images, this event is not recorded by Jmeter also 
How to handle this situation( the third party tool's keys are not exposed to me)

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the image you're trying to upload to JMeter's "bin" folder, given the 3rd-party tool respects browser proxy settings or configured to use JMeter as a proxy you should be able to record the file upload event using [JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details on the approach.

Comment: I have tried copying the file in bin folder but of no help